# Re-configure an existing AppWidget

Tags: android, android-appwidget, htcsense

When I click and hold a widget on the homescreen of my HTC Incredible 2 with the default Sense launcher I get drag destinations for both "Remove" and "Edit" at the bottom of the screen.

How do I enable the use of the "Edit" option in my own widget?  I am only able to run the configuration Activity on widget creation but would like to reopen it with the "Edit" action.  Is this option specific to Sense and not Android in general?

UPDATE:
I can't seem to find any documentation for the HTC API for Android < 4.0.  I also confirmed that this feature is only available on HTC devices and I've only seen it active for HTC widgets.  So I assume that it is only possible to exploit this feature by targeting only HTC devices (stupid idea) or not at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android AOSP doesn't seem to support widget re-configuration..[Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#UpdatingFromTheConfiguration) don't even mention it, apart from initial widget configuration.

I remember that option only using HTC's Sense phones...Anyway also some famous aftermarket distribution [doesn't seem](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6839/how-do-i-configure-existing-power-controls-widget-in-android) to support it, even for pre-installed widgets.

Comment: @Mike re-configuration is possible yourself, if you define an onClick or edit button on your widget, but the HTC sense 'edit' button at the top is a HTC thing yeah.